# Prevent double selected in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Hay i had tried to select `ListView` and change color background of view in selected position to transparent red, but every i tapped or selected an item other item color background also changed too. How to only select and change color background of item i selected ?

[image: Screenshot. I am sorry the app name and logo i deleted in this picture]

this is my `ListView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listFragmentSettingWaktu" />
```

and this is my code

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Asus on 6/4/2015.
 */
public class SettingWaktuFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG_PAGE = "tag_page";
    private static final String TAG_TITLE = "tag_title";
    private int page;
    private String title;
    private ArrayList<JamSibuk> jamList;

    private ListView list;
    private MyBaseAdapter jamAdapter;

    public SettingWaktuFragment newInstance(int page, String title){
        SettingWaktuFragment waktuFragment = new SettingWaktuFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt(TAG_PAGE, page);
        b.putString(TAG_TITLE, title);
        waktuFragment.setArguments(b);
        return waktuFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.page = getArguments().getInt(TAG_PAGE);
        this.title = getArguments().getString(TAG_TITLE);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_setting_waktu_list_jam, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        list = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listFragmentSettingWaktu);

        jamList = new ArrayList<JamSibuk>();
        String jam = null;
        for (int i=0; i<24; i++) {
            if (i < 10)
                jam = "0" + i + ":00";
            else
                jam = i + ":00";
            jamList.add(new JamSibuk(jam, false));
        }
        jamAdapter = new MyBaseAdapter();
        list.setAdapter(jamAdapter);
    }

    private class MyBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        class ViewHolder{
            TextView textView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return jamList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return jamList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView == null)
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);

            final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            holder.textView.setText(jamList.get(position).getJam());
            if(jamList.get(position).isSelected())
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(convertView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent_red));

            holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   if(!jamList.get(position).isSelected())
                       jamList.get(position).setSelected(true);
                    else
                       jamList.get(position).setSelected(false);
                    jamAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it's not selected you have to set a transparent/default color otherwise it will make items red after you make one item red.

```
if(jamList.get(position).isSelected()) {
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(convertView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent_red));
}
else{
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(convertView.getContext().getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Sharj this is work fine. May i ask other topic? this is about `ViewPager` i forgot add this topic in my question. How to prevent `ViewPager` refresh their fragment? for example i selected item in `ListView` in mark it with background color like above at fragment position 1, and i selected item in `ListView` at position 7.when i back to fragment position 1 my selected item is lost, the background is not transparent red.

Comment: You should ask that as separate question. But the basic idea is save information about selected rows in memory, preferably sqlite or worst-case in parent class that created ViewPager.

Comment: ok @Sharj thank you. I'll ask again if i have to try in so much time, if it's stucked i'll ask in separate question. God bless you, thank you

Answer (score 1):

add this to your listview `android:choiceMode="singleChoice"`

Comment: Hello @Sandeep Singh thanks to your answer. I have tried your suggestion but this is still not working

Answer (score 1):

use `onItemClickListener()` instead.

```
ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(convertView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent_red));
        }
```

Comment: thank you @Ahmad Alsanie for your participation to answer my question. i got the way in Sharj's answer

Comment: np, glad you find the answer

Answer (score 0):

the position does not work,your should record the select position outside at the interface onitemclicklistener, and than update the select position in adapter